# Any way to disable the default click animation of a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, transparency, jbutton, translucency

So i have a few JButtons on top of a background image and they are set to be transparent so the background can be seen. When i click the button however, a greyish square appears where the button is while the mouse button is clicked down. This looks kind of ugly and i was wondering if there was any way to disable that animation? Thanks

Comment: What is the Look and Feel that you are using?

Comment: @aterai please is this question based on some graphics lack or bug or :-), my endless curiosity

Comment: sorry, im kind of new to swing, what do you mean by look and feel?

Comment: @mKorbel **Animation** reminds me using a special LnF, but I misunderstood :)

Comment: @user2438514 This could help: [How to Set the Look and Feel (The Java™ Tutorials > Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing > Modifying the Look and Feel)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess..., You can try a `JPanel#setOpaque(false)` method:

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class PanelOpaqueTest {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    JPanel p1 = createPanel();
    p1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("JPanel#setOpaque(false)"));
    p1.setOpaque(false);
    p1.add(createButton());

    JPanel p2 = createPanel();
    p2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("JPanel#setOpaque(true)"));
    p2.setOpaque(true);
    p2.add(createButton());

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
    p.add(p1);
    p.add(p2);
    return p;
  }
  protected JButton createButton() {
    JButton b = new JButton("button");
    b.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    b.setFocusPainted(false);
    //b.setBorderPainted(false);
    //b.setOpaque(false);
    return b;
  }
  protected JPanel createPanel() {
    return new JPanel() {
      @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(new Color(100,100,100,100));
        g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
      }
    };
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new PanelOpaqueTest().makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```